# Trig Substitutions: Why are we allowed to replace $dx$ with $a\ \sec\theta\ \tan\theta$?

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}$, where $a>0$

We let $ x=a\ \sec\ \theta$, where $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}\ or\ \pi<\theta<\frac{3 \pi}{2}$

Then dx = $a\ \sec\ \theta\ \tan\ \theta$?

I understand this chain of calculations:

$\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$

=$\sqrt{a^2(\sec^2\theta-1)}$

=$\sqrt{a^2\ \tan^2 \theta}$

$a|\tan\theta|$

$a\ \tan\ \theta$

Therefore

$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}= \int\frac{a\ \sec\ \theta\ \tan\ \theta}{a\ \tan\ \theta}d \theta$

I do not understand how or why the $dx$ was replaced by:

$a\ \sec\ \theta\ \tan\ \theta$

Seems arbitrary. Is there a rule?

Comment: if y=a sec(x), then what is dy/dx??

Comment: The rule is called integration by substitution...

Comment: Since you changed variable $x$ by variable $\theta$, you need to replace $dx=\frac{dx}{d\theta} \times {d\theta}$. Is this better ?

Comment: it is an inverse trigonometric function substitution $sec^-1$ = $1/rootover(x^2+a^2))